# Is storing too much data in sessions good in Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm working on a project where I'm building a web app using Laravel 5.4.
I'm storing 6 String values in Sessions which gets destroyed after 5 minutes and 2 arrays each having 5-6 string fields which are being destroyed when user logs out or after 30 minutes.

Is this data considered too much for a Session? I'm going to use a VPS for hosting.

Can you guys please suggest me what should i do? Do i keep it this way or change something.

My sessions are currently stored in a file and would it benefit me if i store it in Database?

Please help me I'm a noobie.

Thanks in Advance :) Your guys are really helpful :)

Comment: Are you asking for "best practices"? Traditionally, those sorts of questions don't do well here.

Comment: Kinda something like that i guess I just want to solve my problem.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that the answer is always, "it depends"

Comment: Depends on what? That's what i wanna know so that i can avoid having problems in my Web App in future.

Comment: It depends on many things, most of which we don't know from this question, and then devolves to an opinion. Thew isn't going to attract the best answers, unfortunately, because it doesn't really match up with a QA style intention.

Comment: Ok I get it but can you please help me I'll provide info on everything you need to know. Approx users will be around 5K max, should i update you with my VPS config too?

Comment: This site is not just about helping with a specific problem **now**, but making a body of QA that is useful for someone else **later**. Honestly, you'd do better searching for "best practices sessions laravel" on the web and bootstrapping yourself that way. You might even find existing related Stack Exchange QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess storing that much data is fine. Since you have mentioned it that it will expire in 5 or so minutes. I would also recommend to use redis or memcached for session handling. You can read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy :) Yeah max time for session is 30 minutes only.

Answer (score 1):

storing too much value in session slightly affect the loading time of your page! and that is usual but, the content which you want to store in session does have any significant relation with your business logic  (ie. it has unique id  to identify  user etc. ) then , it is fine to stored in session! I have not used laravel framework but , i have some experience of codelgniter. 
            as far as storing session data in database concern, it give systematic approach to deal with session data. If you stored it in file then you need extra code to assess particular thing form file.
        why don't you used "COOKIE" to stored session data in it , after all it stored it on client side!! session stored it in server-side

Comment: I want my data to be secure and away from users that's why i'm using sessions and not cookies. BTW thanks for your answer :)